# What is the performance difference of MongoDB db.collection.find() with and without filters?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm using MongoDB and mongoose. I want to give different treatments to the same data depending on a condition set by the user. I'm wondering what's the best way to model the data in terms of time performance to get the responses.

*Option 1* has two different collections of documents. When user sets the condition, the document is moved between collections, `...find()` has no filters but the document has to be removed from one collection and added to the other.

*Option 2* has only one collection with a flag in the Scheme of the documents. When user sets the condition the flag in changed, there is no `...delete()`, but `...find()` has filters to catch the flag.

Is there a big difference in time performance between the options? Is there a clear best way to do this or is the difference negligible?

```
//option 1
//schema:
const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    }
});
const DataTrue = mongoose.model("DataTrue", dataSchema);
const DataFalse = mongoose.model("DataFalse", dataSchema);

//when user changes condition:
function changeCondition(nameReferencedByUser) {
    DataTrue.findOneAndDelete({name: nameReferencedByUser}, (err, docRemoved) => {
        if (!err) {
            const inNewCollection = new DataFalse(docRemoved);
            inNewCollection.save();
        }
    });
}

//to query the data:
const toTreatment1 = DataFalse.find({});
const toTreatment2 = DataTrue.find({});
```

```
//option 2
//schema:
const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    condition: Boolean
});
const Data = mongoose.model("DataTrue", dataSchema);

//when user changes condition:
function changeCondition(nameReferencedByUser) {
    Data.updateOne({name: nameReferencedByUser}, {condition: false});
}

//to query the data:
const toTreatment1 = Data.find({condition: true});
const toTreatment2 = Data.find({condition: false});
```

Comment: Using only one collection will certainly be better. In general the number of collections in MongoDB is less much less compared to according application in a RDBMS database.